# Existence of points

Tags: general-topology

Be $X, Y$ two closed subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $X$ bounded. Show the existence of points $x_0 \in X, y_0 \in Y$ such as $d(x_0,y_0) = d(X,Y)=\inf_{x \in X, y \in Y} d(x,y)$.

My idea so far: I want to start by showing that $X_r = \{ y \in  \mathbb{R}^n | d(y,X) \leq r\}$ is compact. With this subspace, without losing generality, I would replace $Y$ by $Y \cap X_r$ for $d(X,Y) \leq r$ where the intersection is nonempty.

Comment: $X$ is closed and bounded, so it's compact. That suggests you might want to look for some open cover of $X$, from which you can pick a finite subcover. Or maybe use some other property of compactness. Do you know any of those?

Comment: Hint:  For any $\epsilon > 0$ there are $x_\epsilon, y_\epsilon$ so that $d(x_\epsilon, y_\epsilon) < d(X,Y) +\epsilon$.  .... And $X$ and $Y$ are closed so......

Comment: @fleablood I did not learn this in my class, so I do not think I am able to use it (my teacher only want us to use the theory we see in class unfotunatly). thank you anyway! :)

Comment: @JohnHughes Yes we did learn some property, I will look into it! thank you for your help!

Comment: yes, you *did* learn that in class.  $d(X,Y)=\inf d(x,y)$.  $\inf$ is that greatest lower bound so $d(X,Y) + \epsilon$ is not a lower bound so there are $(w,v)$ so $d(w,v) < d(X,Y)$.  So make sequences $x_k, y_k$ so that $d(x_k, y_k) < d(X,Y) + \frac 1k$.  The as $X,Y$ are closed....

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$1).\ $ There are sequences $(x_i), (y_i)$ such that $d(x_i,y_i)\to d(X,Y):= m$

$2).\ X$ is compact so there is a convergent subsequence of $(x_i)$ which you may still call  $(x_i)$ for convenience. $(x_i)\to p\in X$

$3).\ $ You may assume that $d(x_i,y_i)\le m+1$ and that $\|x_i\|<R<\infty.$  (Why?).

$4).\ $ Show therefore that $(y_i)$ is bounded and so has a convergent subsequence, which we still call $(y_i)$. Then, $(y_i)\to q\in Y$

$5).\ $ Combine $2$ and $4$ to show that there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k}-y_{n_k})$ that converges to $p-q$ and $p\neq q.$

$5).\ $ Conclude that $d(x_{n_k},y_{n_k})\to p-q=m.$

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help! I am trying to understand why your conlcusion demonstrate what I have to show (the existence of $x_0 \in X$ and $y_0 \in Y$).

Comment: Why do you need $X\cap Y=\emptyset$? If there's a point in $X\cap Y$, then that point can serve as both $x_0$ and $y_0$.

Comment: Yes. I misread the question. I thought the OP wanted the points to be distinct., which wouldn't be the case if the sets were tangent at exactly one point. I will correct. Thanks!

Comment: @Lukas If you work through the hints, I think you will see how the claim follows.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much for your help both of you!

Answer (score 1):

We can assume that $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint. Suppose that $Y$ is bounded. Then, both $X$  and $Y$ are compact, and the result is obvious: Take a sequence $(x_n, y_n)$ in $XxY$ such that $d(x_n,y_n)$ converges to $D=d(X,Y).$ Then, $x_0=\lim x_n$ and $y_0 = \lim y_n.$

Now consider the original question.  Let $C\in X$ satisfy $d(C,Y)\le 2D$ and let $Y_1=Y\cap B,$ where $B$ is the ball of center $C$ and radius $4D.$  Clearly, $d(X,Y)=d(X,Y_1).$  Since $Y_1$ is closed and bounded, we have reduced to the case solved in the first paragraph.

Comment: By taking a subsequence, the sequence $(x_n, y_n)$ can be assumed to be convergent in in $X \times Y.$

Comment: Perfect, thank you for your help!

Comment: Correction: The closed ball $B$ must contain $X$ (arbtrary center) and its radius must exceed the minimum by more that $D.$ Since the "outer annulus" is disjoint to $X,$ the "nearby" points of $Y$ are in $B.$

Comment: Perfect, it's noted!

Answer (score 0):

If you can show / have shown that $d(x,y) : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then you can see this result follows from the fact that a continuous function on compact set attains its extreme values.

Simple case: Assume $X, Y$ are compact. Then $X \times Y$ is compact, and $d(x,y)$ is continuous on this subset. Thus, it attains a minimum at some $(x_0, y_0)$, i.e. there exists $x_0, y_0$ such that
$$d(x_0, y_0) = \inf_{x \in X, y \in Y} d(x,y).$$

Now, in your case $X$ is closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$, hence is compact. However, $Y$ is closed but might not be compact. We just need to replace $Y$ by a compact subset. Intuitively, we can disregard points in $Y$ that could not possibly help us attain the infimum. Thus, let $m = \inf_{x \in X, y \in Y} d(x,y)$, and define
$$ Y' = \{ y \in Y : d(X, y) \le m + 1 \} .$$

Taking closure of $Y'$ if necessary, we can assume that $Y'$ is closed.
Because $X$ is bounded, you can easily show $Y'$ is bounded.
Thus, $Y'$ is closed and bounded, hence compact.

Furthermore, note that $\inf_{x \in X, y \in Y} d(x,y) = \inf_{x \in X, y \in Y'} d(x,y)$. Thus, without loss of generality, we can replace $Y$ by $Y'$, and then apply the simple case.

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)